# JQuery BorderRadius doesn't perform with animation in mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to set border radius for an element with animation like this:

```
$(element).hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({borderRadius : 5});
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({borderRadius : 0});
});
```

when I hover on element, the animation will work Properly. But after hovering out, it won't perform with any animation.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a fiddle? It is working in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk5ojtyt/).

Comment: works for me to, although I used the so code.

Comment: You can, however, add `.stop()` to improve its appearance: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk5ojtyt/1/)

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes that didn't work for me in your fiddle again.
I'm using the latest version of firefox.

Comment: You are right, it isn't working in my firefox too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox the animation isn't working on mouseout. Use CSS instead of javascript here.

Ex: https://codepen.io/patdiola/pen/ZyaYdE

```
button {
  background: blue;
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: border-radius ease-in-out 500ms;
}

button:hover {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#target').hover(function(){
      $(this).addClass('borderIn', 500);
  }, function(){
      $(this).removeClass('borderIn', 500);
  });
});
```

```css
#target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.borderIn {
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I exaggerated your code a little for effect, but it appears to work for me.

```js
$("div").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({borderRadius : 30});
}, function(){
    $(this).animate({borderRadius : 0});
});
```

```css
div{
  height: 70px;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Didn't work for me! my browser is the latest version of firefox .

Comment: I am running 54.0 (32bit) and it works for me... @MajidSadr